# Problems installing django channels and twisted on windows 10 with python 3.8

Tags: django, twisted, django-channels, python-3.8

I am trying to install django channels on windows 10, I have python 3.8.3 and django 3.0.5 already installed. When I enter the command, `pip install channels` in the cmd of the virtual environment of my project, I run into a huge error when my system attempts 'Building wheel for twisted (setup.py)', and upon failing to build this, another giant error occurs when 'Running setup.py install for twisted'.

I have tried downloading the appropriate version of twisted from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted), however when I then open the file using a code editor and try to run it I receive this message:

```
WARNING: Requirement 'Twisted‑20.3.0‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
ERROR: Twisted‑20.3.0‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl is not a valid wheel filename.
```

This issue has been plaguing me for days now and I cannot find the solution anywhere online. Please can someone help me to understand how to resolve this?

Comment: try to upgrade pip to latest version. i had same issue, solved it by upgrading pip. https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I tried this however still receive the same error messages...

Comment: Yes, `pip install Twisted‑20.3.0‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl` returns the above warning and error messages

Comment: I solved the issue by installing [visual studio build tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/) which then allowed me to download twisted

Answer (score 0):

Twisted supports Python 3.7.7 and below, see the Classifiers section of Twisted's [pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/Twisted/). The support for Python 3.8 is [close](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/milestone/Python%203.8%20Support).